# Unable to request.AddBody in RestSharp using for loop

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I want to addbody on Restsharp using for, but it's not working.

```
request.AddBody(new
{
    blue = new []
    {
       for (int=0; i<ss.count();i++)
       {
            new { cus=ss[i], date=ss[i], mangpo=ss[i], namo=ss[i]}
        }
    }    
});
```

Comment: I think have solution for query in mysql sent loop to addbody!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "*Help me now!*" - nobody is obliged to help you - writing something like that is more likely to antagonise than elicit help "now".

Comment: I think I want to use "for loop" in method request.AddBody( );

Comment: I think, I want to use "for loop" query data in mysql and then send to webservice by  request.AddBody function 
But in now! methods  request.AddBody doesn't suppot for loop 
   every one have idea to use methods  request.AddBody and use "for loop" query data my sql 50 rows and sent to json

Answer (score 0):

I think, I want to use "for loop" query data in mysql and then send to webservice by  request.AddBody function 
But in now! methods  request.AddBody doesn't suppot "for loop" 
   Every one have idea to use methods  request.AddBody and use "for loop" query data my sql 50 rows and sent to json format.
   I want to use little Resource!